# Scala - is it possible to write HOF that has varargs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, variadic-functions, higher-order-functions

**Can I have a higher order function that returns a `func(varargs*)`, for example, `(s: String*) => String`?**

I am trying to do the following:

```
  def concatKeys(delimiter: String) = {
    def concat(k1: String, k2: String): String = if (k1.isEmpty) k2 else k1 + delimiter + k2

    (keys: String*) => keys.foldLeft("")(concat)
  }
```

**But when I use it as expected, the code does not compile:**

```
      val key: String = concatKeys(delimiter)(keyAcc, kv._1)
```

If I change it to a `Traversable`:

```
  def concatKeys(delimiter: String) = {
    def concat(k1: String, k2: String): String = if (k1.isEmpty) k2 else k1 + delimiter + k2

    (keys: Traversable[String]) => keys.foldLeft("")(concat)
  }
```

It naturally compiles:

```
      val key: String = concatKeys(delimiter)(Set(keyAcc, kv._1))
```

**So, is not possible to return a HOF with varargs? If not, why not?**

Thank you all!

Comment: There's already a `.mkString` on collections that does this.

Comment: Good to know. :D Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Varargs are not a valid type, they are just sugar syntax that is only available on **methods**, not in **functions**.
Remember that inside the method body, a vararg parameter is actually just a `Seq`

So no, you can't.